# Q: flink on docker

Tags: docker, apache-flink

When I submit a job in JobManager, I need to read a path /file-path. This path should be read from TaskManager, but I actually read /file-path from the submitted machine JobManager, if I want to submit in the JobManager containerHomework, then read the file on the taskmanager, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how a Flink job is submitted, the code in its `main` method is executed either in the client or in the Job Manager. If you want something to be executed in each Task Manager during initialization, put that code into the `open` method of one of your functions.

Comment: I didn't expect this, thank you for your answer.